# passing in sql.oracle.ARRAY SimpleJdbcCall to StoredProcedure

Tags: jdbctemplate

I am using JBoss 7.1.Final as application server and Oracle as database. We are using Spring framework 3.x and Java 6. trying to pass in an array of Strings and convert them inside the stored proc to array of varchars. I haven't found a good example for this yet. Please provide a pointer if you can to any documentation or previous forum post. I have searched and not found one that seems to apply.

The stored proc is defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TEST_CONTENTS
(IN_RR_ARRAY IN RR_ARRAY,
  IN_ORDER_STATE           IN  VARCHAR2,
  OUT_FLAG      OUT VARCHAR2,
  OUT_RETURN_CODE          OUT VARCHAR2,
  OUT_RETURN_DESC          OUT VARCHAR2,
  OUT_RETURN_TYPE          OUT VARCHAR2,
  OUT_RETURN_VAL           OUT NUMBER
  )
```

Type RR_ARRAY is defined as:
create or replace
type RR_ARRAY as table of varchar2(15);

Within my java code I have:

```
jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
this.getTestContents = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withCatalogName("STAR")
        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
        .withProcedureName("GET_TEST_CONTENTS")
        .declareParameters(
                new SqlParameter("IN_RR_ARRAY", OracleTypes.ARRAY,
                        "RR_ARRAY"),
                new SqlParameter("IN_ORDER_STATE", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),                        new SqlOutParameter("OUT_FLAG",
                OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter("OUT_RETURN_VAL", OracleTypes.INTEGER), 
                new SqlOutParameter("OUT_RETURN_CODE", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter("OUT_RETURN_DESC", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter("OUT_RETURN_TYPE", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));

         //I get a different error here so creating new connection for testing
        //conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, user, passwd);
                ArrayDescriptor desc = new ArrayDescriptor("STAR.RR_ARRAY", conn);
        ARRAY arr = new ARRAY(desc, conn, testArray); // testArray is just 
                                                      // String[] with 2 values
        Map<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put("IN_RR_ARRAY", arr);
        hm.put("IN_ORDER_STATE", stateCode);
        hm.put("OUT_FLAG", Types.VARCHAR);
        hm.put("OUT_RETURN_CODE", Types.VARCHAR);
        hm.put("OUT_RETURN_DESC", Types.VARCHAR);
        hm.put("OUT_RETURN_TYPE", Types.VARCHAR);

        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValues(hm);
        Map out = getTestContents .execute(in);
```

The stack trace returned is:

```
11:24:43,691 ERROR [com.test.repository.TestContentsDao] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error while calling GET_TEST_CONTENTS Stored procedure: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call STAR.GET_TEST_CONTENTS(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17059]; Fail to convert to internal representation: oracle.sql.ARRAY@2a081f8f; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: oracle.sql.ARRAY@2a081f8f
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83) [spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80) [spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80) [spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:969) [spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1003) [spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:388) [spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:351) [spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:181) [spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at com.test.repository.TestContentsDao.isGood(TestContentsDao.java:147) [classes:]
```

Any advice or pointers to examples or docs will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I found the fix for this. Now I use this List of Strings:

```java
List<String> ndcList;
```

I changed the array parameter from OracleTypes.ARRAY to java.sql.stypes.ARRAY and specified schema prefix on array name. And changed the code and created a few new convenience methods at the bottom.

I needed the wrapped connection and had to add this dependency to my pom:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

----  method code starts here------------

```java
jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
this.getTestContents = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withCatalogName("STAR")
        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
        .withProcedureName("GET_TEST_CONTENTS")
        .declareParameters(
                new SqlParameter("IN_RR_ARRAY", java.sql.types.ARRAY, "STAR.RR_ARRAY"),
                new SqlParameter("IN_ORDER_STATE", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter("OUT_FLAG", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter("OUT_RETURN_VAL", OracleTypes.INTEGER),
                new SqlOutParameter("OUT_RETURN_CODE", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter("OUT_RETURN_DESC", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter("OUT_RETURN_TYPE", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));

Map<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
hm.put("IN_RR_ARRAY", new ScriptArray(ndcList));
hm.put("IN_ORDER_STATE", stateCode);
hm.put("OUT_FLAG", Types.VARCHAR);
hm.put("OUT_RETURN_CODE", Types.VARCHAR);
hm.put("OUT_RETURN_DESC", Types.VARCHAR);
hm.put("OUT_RETURN_TYPE", Types.VARCHAR);

SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValues(hm);
Map out = getTestContents.execute(in);
----  method code ends here------------

public class ScriptArray extends AbstractSqlTypeValue {
    private List<String> values;

    public ScriptArray(List<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public Object createTypeValue(Connection con, int sqlType,
                                  String typeName) throws SQLException {
        oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection wrappedConnection = con
                .unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
        con = wrappedConnection;
        ArrayDescriptor desc = new ArrayDescriptor(typeName, con);
        return new ARRAY(desc, con,
                (String[]) values.toArray(new String[values.size()]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Been fighting the similar issue for a day. [This article](https://kitefu.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/spring-oracle-stored-procedures-arrays-and-custom-types) helped me.
Here's code backup, in case page will be unavailable:

```
-- custom type
create or replace TYPE "MY_TYPE"
as object(name varchar(255),
value varchar(255))

-- array of MY_TYPE
create or replace
TYPE "MY_ARRAY"
as table of MY_TYPE

-- echo like SP, doesn't do too much
create or replace
procedure foo(
i_array in MY_ARRAY,
o_array out MY_ARRAY)
as
begin
o_array := MY_ARRAY();
for i in 1 .. i_array.count loop

o_array.extend;
o_array(i) := MY_TYPE(i_array(i).name, i_array(i).value);
end loop;
end;
```

Java code:

```
public class FooStoredProcedure {

  private static final String SP_NAME = "FOO";
  private static final String MY_ARRAY = "MY_ARRAY";
  private static final String MY_TYPE = "MY_TYPE";
  private static final String I_ARRAY = "i_array";
  private static final String O_ARRAY = "o_array";


  private final StoredProcedure storedProcedure;

  public FooStoredProcedure(DataSource dataSource) {
    storedProcedure = new StoredProcedure(dataSource, SP_NAME) {
      {
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(I_ARRAY, Types.ARRAY, MY_ARRAY));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(O_ARRAY, Types.ARRAY, MY_ARRAY, new SqlReturnType() {

          @Override
          public Object getTypeValue(CallableStatement cs, int paramIndex,
              int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
            Connection connection = cs.getConnection();
            Map<String, Class<?>> typeMap = connection.getTypeMap();
            typeMap.put(MY_TYPE, MyType.class);

            return cs.getObject(paramIndex);
          }
        }));

        compile();
      }
    };
  }

  /**
   * @return array of {@link MyType} objects or <code>null</code> 
   */
  public MyType[] execute(final MyType[] values) {

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put(I_ARRAY, new AbstractSqlTypeValue() {

      @Override
      protected Object createTypeValue(Connection con, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        ArrayDescriptor descriptor = new ArrayDescriptor(typeName, con);
        return new ARRAY(descriptor, con, values);
      }
    });

    Map<?, ?> result = storedProcedure.execute(params);
    if ((!result.containsKey(O_ARRAY) || result.get(O_ARRAY) == null)) {
      return null;
    }
    try {
      Object[] resultArray = (Object[]) ((ARRAY) result.get(O_ARRAY)).getArray();
      return Arrays.copyOf(resultArray, resultArray.length, MyType[].class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new DataRetrievalFailureException("Unable to retrieve array", e);
    }
  }

  public static class MyType implements SQLData {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
      return MY_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
      name = stream.readString();
      value = stream.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
      stream.writeString(name);
      stream.writeString(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the internet and it was very difficult to get it working with the solution many people have provided.. here is working code example.. in pom.xml create this dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-oracle</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
```

oracle sample code

```
create table employee (EMPNO number(12) not null, FNAME varchar2(60), LNAME varchar2(60), EMAIL varchar2(120));

CREATE SEQUENCE empno_seq  START WITH     1 INCREMENT BY   1 NOCACHE NOCYCLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE employee_type
  AS OBJECT (EMPNO number(12), FNAME varchar2(60), LNAME varchar2(60), EMAIL varchar2(120));
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE employee_table_type AS TABLE OF employee_type;
/

create or replace  PROCEDURE SAVE_EMPLOYEES(p_emp_insert_array in employee_table_type) AS
   BEGIN

   FORALL i IN p_emp_insert_array.first .. p_emp_insert_array.last
            insert into employee(
                    empno,
                    FNAME,
                    LNAME,
                    EMAIL)
                values (
                empno_seq.nextval,
                p_emp_insert_array(i).FNAME,
                p_emp_insert_array(i).LNAME,
                p_emp_insert_array(i).EMAIL
                );

  END SAVE_EMPLOYEES;
  /
```

---

```
import com.abc.employeepoc.domain.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.StructMapper;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Struct;

/**
 *
 * @author rsharma
 */
public class EmployeeStructMapper implements StructMapper<Employee> {

    @Override
    public Struct toStruct(Employee emp, Connection conn, String oracleTypeName) throws SQLException {
        Object[] attributes = {
            emp.getEmpno(),
            emp.getFirstName(),
            emp.getLastName(),
            emp.getEmailAddress()
        };        

        return conn.createStruct(oracleTypeName, attributes);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee fromStruct(Struct struct) throws SQLException {
        Employee emp= new Employee();
        Object[] attributes = struct.getAttributes();
        emp.setEmpno(((Number) attributes[0]).longValue());
        emp.setFirstName(String.valueOf(attributes[1]));
        emp.setLastName(String.valueOf(attributes[2]));
        emp.setEmailAddress(String.valueOf(attributes[3]));        
        return emp;
    }



}
```

SqlStructArrayValue in spring has some issue with OracleConnection casting so i created my own one similar to them.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Struct;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.SqlStructArrayValue;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.StructMapper;

/**
 *
 * @author rsharma
 */
public class OracleSqlStructArrayValue<T> extends SqlStructArrayValue<T> {

    private T[] values;

    /**
     * The object that will do the mapping *
     */
    private StructMapper<T> mapper;

    /**
     * The type name of the STRUCT *
     */
    private String structTypeName;

    /**
     * The type name of the ARRAY *
     */
    private String arrayTypeName;

    public OracleSqlStructArrayValue(T[] values, StructMapper<T> mapper, String structTypeName) {
        super(values, mapper, structTypeName);
        this.values = values;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.structTypeName = structTypeName;
    }

    public OracleSqlStructArrayValue(T[] values, StructMapper<T> mapper, String structTypeName, String arrayTypeName) {
        super(values, mapper, structTypeName, arrayTypeName);
        this.values = values;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.structTypeName = structTypeName;
        this.arrayTypeName = arrayTypeName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createTypeValue(Connection conn, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        if (typeName == null && arrayTypeName == null) {
            throw new InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException(
                    "The typeName for the array is null in this context. Consider setting the arrayTypeName.");
        }
        Struct[] structValues = new Struct[values.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            structValues[i] = mapper.toStruct(values[i], conn, structTypeName);
        }
        OracleConnection oracleConn = (OracleConnection) conn;
        return oracleConn.createOracleArray(typeName != null ? typeName : arrayTypeName, structValues);
    }

}
```

Now in your DAO Class do the following...

```
public class EmployeeDAO {

     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeDAO.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private SimpleJdbcCall saveEmployeesArrayCall;    


    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);        


        this.saveEmployeesArrayCall =
                new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName(SQLConstants.SAVE_EMPLOYEES_STORE_PROC)
                    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                    .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("p_emp_insert_array", Types.ARRAY, SQLConstants.EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE_TYPE));

    }

 public void saveEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {         
                Map<String, Object> in = new HashMap<>();                
        in.put("p_emp_insert_array", new OracleSqlStructArrayValue<>(employees.toArray(new Employee[0]), new EmployeeStructMapper(), SQLConstants.EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TYPE));
        saveEmployeesArrayCall.execute(in);
    }

}


import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import java.util.Objects;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

/**
 *
 * @author rsharma
 */
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable{

    @Id
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The database generated Employee Number")
    private Long empno;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "First Name of the Employee", required = true)
    private String firstName;
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Last Name of the Employee")
    private String lastName;

    private String emailAddress;

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(Long empno, String emailAddress, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.empno = empno;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Long getEmpno() {
        return empno;
    }

    public void setEmpno(Long empno) {
        this.empno = empno;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "empno=" + empno + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", emailAddress=" + emailAddress + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.empno);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.empno, other.empno)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@miracle_the_V @Rajesh Sharma - I have a similar use-case to solve, since we are directly playing with connection and unwrapped oracle connection, are we supposed to close these connections ?

I have found a way to utilize SimpleJdbcCall from Spring JDBC and using OracleConnection to bind Struct and Array values to SqlParameterSource object.

I am actually getting the connection object from DataSourceUtils.getConnection() from which I am unwrapping the OracleConnection object. Are we supposed to close OracleConnection and Connection objects which I pulled from DataSourceUtils.